# Improving performance of generic conversion from DataRow to T

Tags: c#, database, generics, lambda

When querying more than 10k data sets from a `MSSQL` database our software gets pretty slow (more than 10sec loading time). I digged deeper just to find out that they implemented some `Entity`-like generic object conversion from `DataRow` to `T` by calling the contructor of the target type which accepts a `DataRow`.

This loos like this:

```
        List<T> filteredList = new List<T>();
        DataTable dt = ((ITableReader)typeof(T).GetMethod("GetReader").Invoke(null, new object[]{})).GetDataWhere(args);

        Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(DataRow) };
        var constructorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(types);
        var parameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "dataRow");

        Func<DataRow, T> Instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRow, T>>(
                                        Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameters), parameters).Compile();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            filteredList.Add(Instance(row));
        }

        return filteredList;
```

The critical part is the `foreach` where for each row the contructor of the target type is called. Let's assume I have more than 10k data sets, it needs to iterate 10k times and initialize the object each time.

I was thinking about how to improve this but I can't really find a solution. It seems like this needs some general refactoring by avoiding this transformation.

My question therefore is, is there any way to improve the peformance in this case? If not, what should be done otherwise if I want a `List` of objects from my database. Just work with `DataRow`?

Edit: Another Info, we are limited to .NET 4.0

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use Linq for this? 10 seconds for 10K rows is awfully slow IMHO.

Comment: What do the constructors (the ones accepting DataRow as their parameter) look like?

Comment: The constructor does some basic convertion to initialize the parameters of the objects, e.g.:  public WorkScheduleRecord(DataRow Row)
        {
            WorkScheduleID = Convert.ToInt32(Row["Work_Schedule_ID"]);}

Comment: Interesting decision. A data reader/data row does have strong typing, there should be no reason for conversions. I suspect that's where most of the time is spent.

Comment: Instead of digging deeper, how about actually running some profiling and seeing where the slow down occurs exactly?